# How do i append an array(name) in a dictionary and a dictionary item under that same array in a plist?

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, dictionary, plist

I'm creating a quiz app and would like to create a user session function where the user can enter a username to start playing. I have a general idea of appending into a plist but am totally unsure how to append on this branch level(Dictionary>Array>Dictionary) so I would like to know how can I add a username array and add a item dictionary consisting of 2 keys, time and score into the username array. This is what the plist looks like:

[image]

Comment: Are you wanting to add data to the plist manually or programmatically? (in code)

Answer (score 0):

Just point mouse at the end of the item in **Key** column, the (+) and (-) will appear, hit (+). Be sure to expand an array or dictionary before, by clicking the small arrow on the left, otherwise the newly added item will be outside.

[image: Property List]

If you can't catch the (+) with the mouse, try **Editor > Add Item**.